# passing a parameter to a callback function in google Visualizations

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This is how google Visualization examples are.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"], callback: drawVisualization});
```

or

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

How can I pass a parameter to the callback function drawVisualization?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawVisualization(your_parameter);
});
```

Comment: I know this is old, but thanks for this! saved me so much of a headache.

Comment: Brilliant! simple and elegant!